# Issue with if statements in JButton actions

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jframe, actionlistener

I'm pretty new to java, and I've just made a TicTacToe program. I successfully managed to create it with only AI, but when I attempted to add an additional option to play with another human, I ran into an issue. I tried to make it so that if the turncount (defined as a static int) is an even number, it will check if the pressed button's text is equal to nothing, and if so set it to x. Otherwise, it should check to see if the pressed button's text is equal to nothing, and if so set it to O. For whatever reason, it won't seem to check the else statements. The following code is pretty repetitive, so you only need to read the first 12 or so lines to see what I mean. Thanks for helping!

The action listener method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == topl)
            if (turncount % 2 == 0)
            {
                if (topl.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    topl.setText("X");
                    turncount  += 1;
                    winchecker();

                }
            else
                if (topl.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    topl.setText("O");
                    turncount  += 1;
                    winchecker();

                }
            }
        if (e.getSource() == midup)
        {
            if (turncount % 2 == 0)
            {
            if (midup.getText().equals(""))
            {
                midup.setText("X");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
            else
                if (midup.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    midup.setText("O");
                    turncount  += 1;
                    winchecker();

                }
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == topr)
        {
            if (turncount % 2 == 0)
            {
            if (topr.getText().equals(""))
            {
                topr.setText("X");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
            else
                if (topr.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    topr.setText("O");
                    turncount  += 1;
                    winchecker();

                }
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == midl)
        {
            if (turncount % 2 == 0)
            {
            if (midl.getText().equals(""))
            {
                midl.setText("X");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
            else
                if (midl.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    midl.setText("O");
                    turncount  += 1;
                    winchecker();
                }
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == mid)
        {
            if (turncount % 2 == 0)
            {
            if (mid.getText().equals(""))
            {
                mid.setText("X");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
            else
                if (mid.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    mid.setText("O");
                    turncount  += 1;
                    winchecker();

                }
            }           }
        if (e.getSource() == midr)
        {
            if (turncount % 2 == 0)
            {
            if (midr.getText().equals(""))
            {
                midr.setText("X");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
            else
                if (midr.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    midr.setText("O");
                    turncount  += 1;
                    winchecker();

                }
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == botl)
        {
            if (turncount % 2 == 0)
            {
            if (botl.getText().equals(""))
            {
                botl.setText("X");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
            else
                if (botl.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    botl.setText("O");
                    turncount  += 1;
                    winchecker();

                }
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == midlow)
        {
            if (turncount % 2 == 0)
            {
            if (midlow.getText().equals(""))
            {
                midlow.setText("X");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
            else
                if (midlow.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    midlow.setText("O");
                    turncount  += 1;
                    winchecker();

                }
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == botr)
        {
            if (turncount % 2 == 0)
            {
            if (botr.getText().equals(""))
            {
                botr.setText("X");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
            else
                if (botr.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    botr.setText("O");
                    turncount  += 1;
                    winchecker();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the turncount (defined as a static int) is an even number, it will check if the pressed button's text is equal to nothing, and if so set it to x. **Otherwise**, it should check to see if the pressed button's text is equal to nothing, and if so set it to O.

If by otherwise you meant, if `turncount` is odd you need to set `O`; then you need an extra pair of braces `{}` as without them the `else` block would actually match the inner `if` block not outer (and hence never get executed as they match on the same condition that text is `""`).

```
        if (turncount % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (topl.getText().equals(""))
            {
                topl.setText("X");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
        } // ADDED
        else
        { // ADDED
            if (topl.getText().equals(""))
            {
                topl.setText("O");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick, helpful reply. I would upvote, but I don't have a 15 reputation yet.

Comment: @EyedJellyfish, that's okay. You could still accept this as an answer by clicking on the green check mark just below the up vote buttons. Take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about) if you like. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 2):

Your else statement is belonging to the INNER if-statement, not the outer like you intend. Your current code is essentially one big if-block that tests if topl.getText().equals("") twice, which doesn't make sense. So you have this:

```
        if (turncount % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (topl.getText().equals(""))
            {
                topl.setText("X");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
        else 
            if (topl.getText().equals(""))
            {
                topl.setText("O");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
        }
```

And you should change it to become the following:

```
        if (turncount % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (topl.getText().equals(""))
            {
                topl.setText("X");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
        }
        else {
            if (topl.getText().equals(""))
            {
                topl.setText("O");
                turncount  += 1;
                winchecker();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick, helpful reply. I would upvote, but I don't have a 15 reputation yet.

Comment: @EyedJellyfish No need to worry.. +1 on your behalf. :)